# Protractor seems to doesn't work with asynchronous page

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have a HTML page which is fill in a asynchronous way in javascript. I create an integration test with protractor but when the test begin, I can't have access to element of the DOM of the page

At the beginning of the protractor test i need to have access of one element of the DOM to check if it is filled correctly. No Way. I cannot have access to this element.

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
condition = EC.presenceOf($('[id=asyncContentId]'));
browser.wait(condition, 5000, "asyncContentId not ready");
```

Expect : I Need the DOM element 'asyncContentId'

Unfortunatelly I never have access to this DOM element.

I Use Jasmine 2.1
This is my last version ans it doesn't work : 
 it("Test Ajax applicatif", function(done) {

```
      console.log("Tests Ajax");
      var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
      element(by.id('btnMenu')).isDisplayed().then(function(displayed) { if (displayed) { browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable($('[id=btnMenu]')), 8000); element(by.id('btnMenu')).click(); } });
      browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable($('[id=Configuration]')), 8000);
      element(by.id('Ajax')).click().then( function(result) {
          browser.wait(protractor.until.elementLocated(by.id('asyncContentId')), 8000, "Element asyncContentId Non trouvé");
    }, function( error ) {
        console.log("error");
        // eslint-disable-next-line dot-notation
    }).finally(done);
```

});
});

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** The following is an async / await example of how you could wait for an element to be present. If you are not using async / await, I insist that you do since the control flow has been deprecated by selenium-webdriver for a while.

**Side note:** ExpectedConditions might require Angular synchronization and I can't remember if it did or not.

In the following example, you could write your own function to check if the element exists.

```
// Turn off sychronization if we are not on an Angular page.
await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

// Wait for the element to be present. This might throw an error when trying
// to find an element, in that case, return false and keep polling for the element
await browser.wait(async () => {
  try {
    return element(by.css('[id="asyncContentId"]')).isPresent();
  } catch (err) {
    // catch the thrown error when webdriver does not find the element
    // and return false so we can still continue to poll.
    return false;
  }
}, 5000, 'asyncContentId is not present.');
```

Comment: Hi! If waitForAngular is disabled for browser instance, then expected conditions won't be waiting for angular as well, since EC.presenceOf is still calling isPresent inside

Comment: Oh neat. I haven't dug into EC and waitForAngular in a while.

Comment: Thanks, but My Jasmine is 2.1, and the solution cannot be implemented. Is everyone has a solution ? Thanks in advance

Comment: At least, here my solution in jasmine 2.1 which doesn't work at all :